# using an R list in WHERE clause of SQL query

Tags: sql, r, teradata

I am attempting to use a list of values from a table in the WHERE clause of a SQL query. Specifically, if pat_ids is my list, e.g. pat_list= c('abc','xyz','123'), I attempt to run (in R)

```
library('RODBC')
edw = odbcConnect('Teradata')
allVisit = sqlQuery(
    edw,
    "SELECT
        fe.*
        FROM edwcdm_pc_views.fact_encounter AS fe
            JOIN edwcdm_pc_views.fact_diagnosis AS fd on   fe.encounter_sk = fd.encounter_sk
        WHERE
        fe.Patient_Sk in paste("(",paste(pat_ids,collapse=","),")",sep="")
")
```

I get the error "unexpected string constant in WHERE fe.Patient_Sk

What I am doing wrong exactly? Am I not reformatting the list correctly as a string for the SQL WHERE clause, or is there a more fundamental problem with the syntax of trying to use an R object as a SQL query term?

Comment: It goes `paste("SELECT ... (",paste(...),")")`. You paste the first part of the query to the second part.

Comment: I don't think I understand. What you suggest (having the paste before SELECT) would simply turn the entire query into an R string.

Comment: Exactly. The SQL you pass from R to sqlQuery is a string.

Comment: same question and answer than : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618205/call-r-dataframe-in-sql/53621622 :)

Comment: Alternatively, Teradata or SQL in general does not have the `paste` command which is an R method. Everything sent to the Teradata database engine must comply to Teradata's SQL dialect. Remember two languages are working here: R as application layer and SQL as the lower-level database layer.

Comment: You're trying to put a `"` inside another `"`, but instead just closing that string. Use `"` for wrapping the SQL query and `'` inside `paste`, or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

The glue package has a handy function `glue_sql` which solves this problem:

```
glue::glue_sql(
  "
  SELECT
    fe.*
  FROM 
    edwcdm_pc_views.fact_encounter AS fe
    JOIN edwcdm_pc_views.fact_diagnosis AS fd on fe.encounter_sk = fd.encounter_sk
  WHERE
    fe.Patient_Sk in ({pat_list*})
  ",
  .con = edw
)
#<SQL> SELECT
#  fe.*
#FROM 
#  edwcdm_pc_views.fact_encounter AS fe
#  JOIN edwcdm_pc_views.fact_diagnosis AS fd on   fe.encounter_sk = fd.encounter_sk
#WHERE
#  fe.Patient_Sk in ('abc', 'xyz', '123')
```